# Can I make a straight line in Photoshop and rotate it without it getting pixelated?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pixelation

I want to draw a straight line in photoshop without it getting pixelated when I rotate it at any particular angle. Is there a way of doing that?There are numerous solutions in google but none works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you  name some of those 'numerous Google solutions' and why they didn't meet your standards? Thanks!

Comment: This answer at sometime will be on "Google too". It is better to understand what is happening.

Comment: One asked you to save the image in PNG-8 instead of PNG-24. The other  was shift+draw the line. Both were not helpful.

Comment: related and possible duplicate: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20394/how-to-remove-jagged-edge-aliasing-on-a-straight-diagonal-line

Comment: Are you sure you mean pixelated? And not aliased instead? There is a huge difference but laymen usually call them both the same. Like vincent pragmatically says is that everything on your sceen is pixelated (And often prints too). But aliased we can do something about.

Comment: Also have a look at http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1812/how-do-i-turn-off-anti-aliasing-while-drawing-shapes-in-photoshop

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: That is impossible. Only media that do not use pixels to be displayed can be unpixelated.

Photoshop is, in the end, a raster image program. That means that any file* you make in or export from Photoshop is defined as having pixels. No matter how small those pixels are, you will always see pixels and, thus, pixelation.

If you want truly unpixelated lines, use a vector image editor like Illustrator or Inkscape. Then still, if you export from those into a file format that is defined as having pixels (`*.jpg`, `*.png`, `*.tiff` to name a few), lines will still be pixelated.

Even vector files, themselves fully pixel-less, will be pixelated when they are displayed on a screen—which can only output pixels.

The only kind of files that can truly be unpixelated are `*.pdf`s of vector images, which are then printed.

There are ways to **reduce** the impact of pixelation on-screen. A good example is [anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersampling), where some neighbouring pixels are given a transitional colour to make the edges somewhat fuzzy. This reduces the pixelation effect, especially when the actual pixels are too small to be seen separately.

<sup><sub>*In theory, it is possible to only draw vector shapes in Photoshop, and export the result as a `.pdf`. That is anything but practical, and better done in Illustrator.</sub></sup>

Comment: So drawing the line in illustrator will help?

Comment: @Dev That depends on the end result. Judging by the [tag:website-design] you had on the question, the end result is going to be for a screen. Which is always pixelated. So, no, that won't help and all you can do is reduce the pixelation's ugliness with anti-aliasing.

Comment: I love the fine print :) also great, concise answer!

Answer (score -1):

Use the Paths panel to create a vector path in Photoshop. You can then Stroke, Fill, Rotate it, or work with it in ways similar to Illustrator. Paths can be a bit tricky--you may want to review some tutorials on using Paths in Photoshop.