# Why is my Line Tool In Photoshop making blurry lines?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, anti-aliasing, adobe-photoshop-elements

I am using the line tool in Photoshop but my lines keep coming out blurry like this:

[image]

Why is this the case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Remove Jagged Edge (Aliasing) on a Straight Diagonal Line](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20394/how-to-remove-jagged-edge-aliasing-on-a-straight-diagonal-line)

Comment: @JohnManly: I disagree - this could be more a case of bad image set-up.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether this should actually be just a comment, but the reason you're getting blurred, slightly jagged edges, is because you're using the line tool on a fairly low resolution image and are zoomed in.

[image: Zoomed line image]

Try changing your zoom to 100% and see if the jaggedness remains.  If you need more detail, then consider changing the resolution of your image (either change the X/Y pixel count or change the number pixels per unit).

Comment: How can you tell the zoom level from the image the OP posted?  I was going to suggest this as well, but who's to say how zoomed in they really are?

Comment: I tried several approaches to replicate what they were doing and this was the most logical. The fact that the image is very pixelated crosse with the fact that there's obviously some anti-aliasing going on with the drawn lines would point to this.

Answer (score -1):

I find if you use these settings (icon toolbar) you get 'clean' lines.

regards[image]

Answer (score -2):

To solve this issue. increase the ppi. pixels per inch.make it to 300 ppi.

Comment: Welcome! Please explain better what you mean ...

Comment: Hi Tippu, thanks for contributing. While this might be a solution, we usually prefer some explanation on _why_ something works, so the questioner and future passers-by can understand how a certain setting influences their work. Could you [edit] your answer and elaborate on why you think increasing PPI would make the jagged lines go away?